# Различный _score для одинаковых документов. Отличаются поисковые выдачи для одинаковых запросов

Tags: машинное-обучение, search, elasticsearch, полнотекстовый-поиск

Добавляю документ в коллекцию с помощью insert или с помощью bulk API. Приведу пример:

```
{
    "tokens": "makita"
}
```

Затем, делаю полнотекстовый поиск по индексу. Оказывается, что добавленный документ появляется в выдаче не каждый раз среди найденных документов. Вторая проблема. Документы имеют разные значения в поле `_score`. Если я запрашиваю `explain=True`, в таком случае `docCount`и `docFreq` у них различный. Как объяснить такое поведение системы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в разных шардах лежат различные данные. Из-за этого поисковая выдача может немного отличаться и отдавать разнличные ответы. Такое поведение у `elasticsearch` по дефолту. Проблема решается тем, что следует указать количество шардов == 1, количество реплик == 0. Эти параметры выставляются при создании индекса.